# Group classes or traits unto one base class

Tags: php

I'm achieving something like create component base application e.g.

```
-- loader.php
    -- comonents folder
        -- router.php
        -- database.php
        -- payment.php
        -- other components...
```

In `loader.php` consist of a base class supposedly which will group all components file from components folder so front app can access all components through that base class e.g.

loader.php

```
class loader{
    // components here
}

$loader = new loader;
```

then in my front app I can just do..

index.php

```
<?php require_once(__DIR__.'/loader.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php $loader->router(); ?> // get router.php component and use
    </head>
    ....
```

Now, components can be created using `php trait` and just do

```
class loader{
    use Router, Database...; // put all traits
}
```

so they can be accessible through the loader class but the problem is whenever I create or delete a component, I don't want to go to `class loader` to edit the call of all of the traits, it should be automatically reflected. In current capability of a php reflection and inheritance, seems not possible. Is there a way in PHP to achieve this such idea?

I can create a config and add all components file name e.g.

```
$config['components'] = [ 'Router', 'Database' ...
```

and just do this in `loader.php` and eliminate the base class

```
foreach( $config as $c ){
   require_once(__DIR__.'/components/'.$c.'.php');
   $$c = new $c(); // array value to variable then initialize component class using array value since name all the way are the same
}
```

then in front app, do

```
<?php require_once(__DIR__.'/loader.php'); ?> // compose of loop components

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php $router(); ?> // get router.php component and use
    </head>
```

But as much as possible I don't want to do that, I want to group all traits or class base components if possible to a one base class then just that base class will be callable to the front app (index.php).

Comment: *”I don't want to go to class loader to edit the call of all of the traits”* - Even if you can automate the addition/removal of the traits, you will still need to edit the code in your “front app” which *calls* these trait methods, otherwise they will break in a spectacular fashion. You can’t get around breaking and changing *something* when you alter components, so how often is this going to happen in the first place and how much work are you saving by automating this? Hardcoding traits gives IDEs and such a much better chance to highlight everything that’ll break for you.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of that case, I just want to find ways on how to achieve that idea above without going to the base class and update the declaration of the traits.